# WinMerge : filter some file extension only for existence, not for difference in content

Tags: winmerge

I'm using WinMerge to compare folders with subfolders and different file types. There are basically png files, script files named .x and their compiled versions named .xc . I already have a filter showing me only the different files and ignoring the similar ones.

I would like the .xc to *only* appear in the structure if abc.xc is present in oe of the folders but not the other. If there is a abc.xc in both and their content is different, I'm not interested. And I want all other files to be compared normally : if two pngs are present under the same name but different in content, I want to know, same for text files and whatnot.

I already found how to exclude .xc files from consideration altogether, using a filter, but I don't know if this particular thingy is doable.

Comment: You will need two types of compare - you can't have two different searches in one compare. The WinMerge Compare window has a Save & Load project button which can help with the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done in WinMerge in one go.
You will need two types of compare - you can't have two different searches
in one compare.

The WinMerge Open/Compare window has a Save & Load Project button
which can help with the two.

See
[WinMerge Project files](https://manual.winmerge.org/en/Open_paths.html#OpenPaths_project).

Answer (score 0):

So, Windows, ...

Note that your question can be seen as a request for a free script.
superuser was never intended to be a free-script-writing service.

---

Do this in the two folders you wish to compare:
`C:\> dir /s /b >list_of_files.txt`

Then compare those two files with a diff utility of your choice.

That might be a good start for the remainder of your comparison journey.
The more complex your wishes become the more reason you will have to use e.g. a home brew Python script instead.

Note that Python is fairly simple to learn, it has a load of options, and might also have an optional module to help you out.
There are MANY modules out there, many of them of high quality too.